# Div Background image disappears

Tags: html, css

Hi I am trying to add a image as background to a div. it works when window is maximized, but when i change the size of the window, the image disappears.

Can you please let me know where i am going wrong.

```
background-image: url('../Images/IPCC-Tile.jpg');
background-color: #FFFFFF;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
position: absolute;
width: 15%;
height: 35%;
top: 30%;
left: 2%;
overflow:visible;
```

thank you.

Comment: i guess the problem is with the overflow visible, can you try overflow: hidden?

Comment: Yes, i have tried that too. Still doesn't work :(

Comment: Why are you using both background-image and background-color? I assume that if you remove the background-color property it might fix this problem.

Comment: I just removed that. but still no luck. by the way image itself is white color...it works when maximized.

Comment: can you show this in jsFiddle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
background-image: url('../Images/IPCC-Tile.jpg');
background-color: #FFFFFF;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
background-size:contain; 
position: absolute;
width: 15%;
height: 35%;
top: 30%;
left: 2%;
overflow:visible;
```

Set the value of `background-size` to `cover` or `contain`, it doesn't matter.

Comment: It worked for me until I used "position:absolute". Why do you need to have an absolute position?

Comment: @JaimeMontoya,  I can infer that you experienced that because the image was too big. hence it was only given a display priority when its position is absolute. 
if you have set the height to something small `i.e 8px` you would have seen it displayed.

The above is however with respect to a personal experience. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
background:#ffffff url('../Images/IPCC-Tile.jpg') no-repeat center center;
```

or maybe [this will help you as well](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?554712-CSS-disappearing-background-when-browser-resized).